# Regular Expression - check if a string starts and end with a/b

Tags: regex

I was working on a coding test and it's essentially the same as this problem - [link](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/1473342/amazon-oa)

The answer I came up with is `^[ab]$|^([ab]).*\1$` and for some reason it keeps failing the tests. For example testcase `"aba"` will fail.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If the starting a or b should be the same as the ending, you can use the backreference like `^([ab]).*\1$` which will match https://regex101.com/r/JAktDy/1

Comment: Probably you can use: `^([ab])(?:.*\1)?$`

Comment: You must explain how you are using the pattern. Is it the case when you need to double backslashes or use raw string literals?

Comment: You are not missing anything. This pattern works ( also on `"aba"`). See https://regex101.com/r/meTDru/2 . What you are maybe missing is to put the regex pattern in a RAW string to avoid that the regex function does not get the right pattern and the ` \ ` is interpreted as an escape character in the string with the regex pattern ( or change it to `^[ab]$|^([ab]).*\\1$` ). Does this solve your problem?